# How to use BeforeTextChanging event of TextBox in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, event-handling, winui-3

Would somebody pls explain how to properly use the [BeforeTextChanging](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.beforetextchanging?view=winrt-22621) event in WinUI3?

As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.beforetextchanging?view=winrt-22621) suggest I tried this in the xaml file

```
<TextBox x:Name="LicencePlateInputBox" BeforeTextChanging="HandleLicencePlateNumber"/>
```

However, since I do not know, what the event signature

```
public event TypedEventHandler<TextBox,TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs> BeforeTextChanging;
```

tells us, I just did this in the cs file

```
private void HandleLicencePlateNumber(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
}
```

But I get

```
Error   CS0123  No overload for 'HandleLicencePlateNumber' matches delegate 'TypedEventHandler<TextBox, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the event handler like this, i.e. the type of the second argument should be `TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs`:

```
private void HandleLicencePlateNumber(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    
}
```